# Need transposed apply output at each step

Tags: r, apply, transpose

I want to fill in a matrix row-by-row, applying a function to the previous row to generate the next row. I'm a newbie trying to use `apply` instead of the obvious `for` loop. However, because `apply` returns the result as a column vector, when it moves to the next row, that row doesn't have the necessary contents. Here's an example where each row should be the double of the previous row, with a starting row.

```
trial <- matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 5)
trial[1,] <- c(1, 2, 3)
trial[2:5, ] <- apply(trial[1:4, ], MARGIN = 1, function(x) (x * 2))
trial
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2   NA   NA
[3,]    4   NA   NA
[4,]    6   NA   NA
[5,]   NA   NA   NA
```

What I would like is something like this:

```
for(i in 2:5){
   trial[i,] <- trial[i-1,] * 2
  }
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    4    6
[3,]    4    8   12
[4,]    8   16   24
[5,]   16   32   48
```

I don't see a way to use transpose either inside or outside `apply` to get it to return a row vector as it goes down the rows.
Is `apply` just not the right solution here? Am I trying too hard to avoid a `for` loop and do things the R way?

Comment: All R's `*apply*` functions work on the iterated elements independently. If you need the ith row to build upon the previous row, you need to use a for-loop.

Comment: I highly recommend a look into Hadley Wickhams [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html), check the section on loops. As @MrGumble said, in your case you have to use a `for` loop. You have already used the "fast way" to use loops by initializing the object you want to loop over and not growing it within the loop (just wanted to note this so that you keep your way of using loops).

Comment: There's no answer to accept, but your replies answered my question. Thanks! The reference to Advanced R was great.